# Apache duplicate every GET request made by Googlebot

Tags: apache-2.2, request, googlebot

System: Linux 3.10.47.core2.24
Apache: Most likely version 2.2 (can`t check that)
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Apache API Version: 20051115

In logs requests looks like this:

```
94.*.*.* - - [26/Nov/2014:01:06:52 +0100] "GET /zegarki/adriatica/zegarek_adriatica_A3515.1173QZ.html HTTP/1.0" 200 55303 "-" "-" 94 55655 zegarek 317 68 0 0
66.249.67.15 - - [26/Nov/2014:01:06:52 +0100] "GET /zegarki/adriatica/zegarek_adriatica_A3515.1173QZ.html HTTP/1.1" 200 15220 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" 282 15481 zegarek 6 3 0 0
```

Same schema repeats every Googlebot visit. This way server generates 15% load a day, which is quite a big number (for useless action).

EDIT:
My question is: what can generate such duplicates? Where should I search for source for this trouble?

I have already checked most of php files on website and no injected code was found.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You have right Peter, just edited my post.

Comment: Are you implying something else is happening besides two nodes sending GET requests?

Comment: I just have no idea what is running GET request on server (by server) and why only with Googlebot.
Can it be that server is redirecting HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/1.0?

Comment: Proxy or rewriterule [P] directives? Is the source IP the webservers?